# Google api scope (email + plus.login) change

Tags: google-plus

Last month I was using scopes `['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login']`

without any issues, now I've started to get warning:

`Warning: Scope has changed from "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"`

After I changed this, everything is OK but I'm wondering why it's here in documentation as deprecated?
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#deprecated-scopes

I'm quite confused why it won't work with scopes `['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login']` anymore. Is it safe to use or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login is deprecated but for a few weeks (I was on vacation and I can not know at what time) the domain-wide delegation in which I used this scope ( together with others) has stopped working. Not so the use of this scope in the validation.

I really went crazy until I found that the reason for the errors I got was due to this scope.

Once the scope has been removed from the list, everything has returned to normal.